# Random forest object not loading

Tags: r, class, load, random-forest

I am saving two random forest objects as a rda files. When I load them-  One loads as character and the other loads as randomForest object! Can someone explain this?

Here is my code snippet :

```
fit1 <- load("rfModel_pw2.rda")
fit2 <- load("rfModel_pw3.rda")
Pred1 <- predict(get(fit1), test, "prob")
#Error in get(fit1) : invalid first argument
Pred2 <- predict(get(fit2), test, "prob")
class(fit1)
#[1] "randomForest.formula" "randomForest" 
> class(fit2)
#[1] "character"
```

Comment: could you show how the models were trained and saved?

Comment: @SorenHavelundWelling   Here is the training code snippet : fit_noResponse <- randomForest(as.factor(renewed) ~  <list of properties>, data=train, importance=TRUE, ntree=1000, mtry = 4, proximity = TRUE)                                                                                For saving, this is my code :save(fit_noResponse,file = "rfmodel_pw_noResponse.rda")

Answer (score 0):

`load()` places loaded objects from .rda file in global environment automatically and returns only the character names of loaded objects. Instead of using `get([name])` simply use the same object-name before saving and after loading, as in example. Otherwise if you like the loader function to return loaded object, you can replace `load()` / `save()` with `saveRDS()` / `readRDS()`.

```
library(randomForest)
X = replicate(2,rnorm(1000))
y = apply(X,1,sum) 
rf = randomForest(X,y)
save(rf,file="./rf.rda")

rm(list=ls())
load(file="./rf.rda") #object is restored in global enviroment by former name
predict(rf,replicate(2,rnorm(1000)))
```